Error with Tokenizer parallelism when using gradio and mlflow
I have written a script using gradio and sometimes (I emphasize this- only sometimes) when I run it I get
huggingface/tokenizers: The current process just got forked, after parallelism has already been used. Disabling parallelism to avoid deadlocks...
To disable this warning, you can either:
    - Avoid using `tokenizers` before the fork if possible
    - Explicitly set the environment variable TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=(true | false)

The strange thing is that different to the answers I got searching the internet , I am not using tokenizers, or LLMs or accessing huggingface models or forking anything.
My code is simply a gradio script that uses dropdowns buttons and dataframes and that when clicked it sends a request to a remote machine. This remote machine is running an API that actually calls a LLava model, but that is process running on a remote machine.
The local machine- where the error is displayed- just sends a request and receives it
The only other thing that occurs to me is that when the process is finished I do
with mlflow.start_run() as run:
    mlflow.log_param("some_param",something)
    # ... some more param metrics and artifacts logging
    print(
                f"Logged data to MLFlow with run ID: {run.info.run_id} in experiment: {experiment_name}"
            )

The error message appears in this moment and before the final print
Any hint of why this could be happening?

It's not an error message, it's a warning. If you want to get rid if the message follow what it's saying.

yes, but I would like to know why it is happening sometimes

"fork" is a multiprocessing mode - https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html, and the huggingface tokenizer library uses rust as a backend. In order to prevent threading issues, if the tokenizer library detects that the caller has forked it runs single threaded.

but I am not using a tokenizer or doing a fork... unless mlflow start_run forks a process??

Presumably you're using a model based on transformers?, They use tokeniziers. It's pretty common for ML libraries to fork so yeah I'd imagine mlflow does it.
